# Override toString en una herencia de clases de C++

Tags: c++

estoy tratando de implementar un método `toString()` para las clases de abajo pero no estoy logrando hacer que funcione, al momento de acceder al método, solo se ejecuta el que está en la clase `Vehiculo`. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿puede que tenga que usar `override`?

En los hpp tengo esto:

```
class Vehiculo{
   virtual string toString();
}

class Auto : Vehiculo {
  string toString();
}
```

En los cpp tengo esto:

```
string Avion :: toString() {
  return "esto es un avion";
}


class Avion : Vehiculo {
  string toString();
}


string Auto :: toString() {
  return "esto es un auto";// ademas me interesa que se pueda acceder al toString de Vehiculo
}
```

Pero no estoy logrando lo que quiero, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
class Vehiculo{
   virtual string toString();
}
```

En `class` la visibilidad de los elementos es, por defecto, privada. Esto quiere decir que únicamente los miembros de `Vehiculo` podrán acceder. Para cambiar esta visibilidad tienes que indicarlo expresamente:

```
class Vehiculo{
public: // <<--- Visibilidad publica
   virtual string toString();
}
```

Y lo mismo pasa con las herencias... si usas `class` las herencias serán privadas salvo que se indique lo contrario... ¿Qué implica que una herencia sea privada?

Es un poco más enrevesado de explicar pero simplificando un poco se podría decir que la herencia no será visible... como si no existiese para nadie salvo para la clase que recibe la herencia.

De momento por simplificar tu vida procura no usar herencia privada:

```
class Auto : public Vehiculo {
//           ^^^^^^ herencia publica
  string toString();
}
```

**Nota:** Por cierto, las declaración de una clase debe finalizar **siempre** con punto y coma:

```
class Vehiculo{
public:
   virtual string toString();
}; // <<--- Importante!!!
```

> ¿puede que tenga que usar `override`?

`override` es una palabra reservada que está disponible desde el estándar C++11 y únicamente sirve para que el compilador nos ayude a detectar inconsistencias al sobreescribir funciones. Cuando tu marcas una función como `override` lo único que haces es indicarle al compilador que debe verificar lo siguiente:

- Que en alguna clase padre existe una función con **exactamente** la misma declaración
- Que la función de la clase padre está marcada como `virtual`

Es decir:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void Func1(int) const;
  virtual void Func2(int) const;
  virtual void Func3(int) const;
  virtual int Func4(int) const;

  void Func5();
};

struct Derivada : Base
{
  void Func1(int) const override; // OK
  void Func2(int) override;       // ERROR: falta const
  void Func3() const override;    // ERROR: falta el argumento int
  void Func4(int) const override; // ERROR: el tipo de retorno no es el mismo
  void Func5() override;          // ERROR: Base::Func5 no es virtual
};
```

Si en el ejemplo anterior no hubiésemos usado `override` el compilador no nos avisaría de esos errores y el programa final, muy seguramente, no funcionaría como esperamos.

> ademas me interesa que se pueda acceder al `toString` de `Vehiculo`

Puedes forzar la llamada a la función de la clase padre con `Vehiculo::`:

```
string Auto::toString() {
  return "esto es un auto\n" + Vehiculo::toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estuve probando tu codigo en Visual C++, supongo que copiastes mal porque tenias problemas de falta de punto y coma.
También raro que pudieras acceder a toString() porque esta declarado como privado.
Además la herencia no era publica.
No pusistes la implementación de la clase Vehiculo
Yo el toString() de Vehiculo lo declararia como virtual puro.

```
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Vehiculo
{
public:
    virtual string toString(); // Esto personalmente lo declararía virtual puro
};
class Auto : public Vehiculo
{
    string toString();
};
class Avion : public Vehiculo
{
    string toString();
};

string Vehiculo :: toString() { return "esto es un vehiculo"; }
string Avion    :: toString() { return "esto es un avion"; }
string Auto     :: toString() { return "esto es un auto"; }

void main()
{
    Vehiculo* v1 = new Vehiculo();
    Vehiculo* v2 = new Avion();
    Vehiculo* v3 = new Auto();
    printf("v1: %s\n", v1->toString().c_str());
    printf("v2: %s\n", v2->toString().c_str());
    printf("v3: %s\n", v3->toString().c_str());
    delete v1;
    delete v2;
    delete v3;
    getch();
}
```